# Issues compiling

Tags: python, 20.04, compiling

I am using [this method](https://github.com/lsw9021/MASS) for research I am doing, but I am having some difficulties with the setup. About half way down the page it says to run `./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3 sudo ./b2 --with-python --with-filesystem --with-system --with-regex install`, then marks what the response should be. It worked almost perfectly, but there are a few files that I cannot figure out how to install; notably `/usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so` and `/usr/local/lib/libboost_numpy3.so`. Below is the full response: (note that `root@cole-desktop:/home/cole/Downloads/Mass/boost_1_66_0# ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3` was autofilled and I just hit enter.)

```
   Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 3.8
Detecting Python root... /usr
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Backing up existing Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam.2
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2
    
To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

   - Command line help:
     ./b2 --help
     
   - Getting started guide: 
     http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html
     
   - Boost.Build documentation:
     http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html

root@cole-desktop:/home/cole/Downloads/Mass/boost_1_66_0# sudo ./b2 --with-python --with-filesystem --with-system --with-regex install
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
    - 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
    - symlinks supported       : yes (cached)
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - fiber                    : not building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - stacktrace               : not building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - type_erasure             : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...patience...
...found 31231 targets...
...updating 11 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o
libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp: In function ‘void* boost::python::converter::{anonymous}::convert_to_cstring(PyObject*)’:
libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp:51:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
   51 |       return PyUnicode_Check(obj) ? _PyUnicode_AsString(obj) : 0;

    "g++"   -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -I"/usr/include/python3.8" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o" "libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.so.1.66.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>converter/builtin_converters.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_python3.so.1.66.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.so.1.66.0...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_python3.so for lack of <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_python3.so.1.66.0...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_numpy3.so.1.66.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.so.1.66.0...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_numpy3.so.1.66.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_numpy3.so.1.66.0...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_numpy3.so for lack of <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_numpy3.so.1.66.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o
libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp: In function ‘void* boost::python::converter::{anonymous}::convert_to_cstring(PyObject*)’:
libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp:51:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
   51 |       return PyUnicode_Check(obj) ? _PyUnicode_AsString(obj) : 0;

    "g++"   -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -DNDEBUG  -I"." -I"/usr/include/python3.8" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o" "libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/converter/builtin_converters.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>converter/builtin_converters.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>converter/builtin_converters.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_python3.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-gnu-9/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi>libboost_python3.a...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 9 targets...
```

I believe the issue to be related to the computer failing to find some pathway within `pbin.v2`, but I have no idea what/where that is.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same identical situation.

What worked for me was

```
sudo cp -r /usr/local/include/python3.6m/ /usr/local/include/python3.6/
```

I am not sure what kind of Python configuration you have but the solution is to copy (or create a soft link) as in the command above.
The problem is that Boost looks for pyconfig.h in the python folder without the m that doesn't not exist.